# What type of weatherstripping has two mating metal strips?

Tags: doors, door-frame, weatherstripping

We have a door on one of our entry ways that has this sort of aluminum weather stripping. One part attaches to the door, the other to the frame, and then they sort of fit together in an interlocking fashion.

A portion has broken off, and I'm hoping to find a replacement for purchase, as opposed to replacing the entire setup.

I've googled and searched, but haven't found this type anywhere. Do any of you know what this type of stripping would be called?

Thanks so much in advance.

[image: Broken from this point to bottom]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it’s called “interlocking”. Try Pemko Interlocking Weatherstripping and you’ll find several like this:

https://hardwarelocker.com/pemko-b41-96-interlock-weatherstrip-96in-mill-brass

Answer (score 1):

"Meeting rail", either flat or hooked. Yours is galvanized steel, not aluminum.